# Get output from Telnet

Tags: java, telnet

does anybody know how to read output from telnet with Java? I'm able to connect to
the server and execute some commands, but I need output from that commands.

For example, command ls gives a list of all files and directory so I want to get that
list and do something with it in my Java code.

I had tried 3rd party libraries for Telnet like apache-commons and sinetfactory(www.jscape.com
) but with no results for my case...

Igor

Answer (score 3):

You can read the output from the process `InputStream`, something like this:

```
final Process process =
    new ProcessBuilder("path/to/telnet", "and", "some", "args").start();
final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
final InputStream processData = process.getInputStream();

// start a thread to read process output
new Thread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(running.get()){

            // read processData

        }

    }
}).start();
process.waitFor();
running.set(false);
```

Comment: I can start telnet session using Process or ProcessBuilder classes but then I can't execute commands on that process. I tried by opening output stream of process but it didn't work. For example,  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("telnet ip port"); PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream()); out.println("ls"); out.close(); but nothing recieved...

Comment: not sure if you still need a solution but I made something [simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988029/java-telnet-library/14098926#14098926) (and EXTREMELY limited in scope) that might help

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for a java solution, but the expect scripting language was developed for this type of thing.  http://expect.sourceforge.net/

If it *has* to be java, then please disregard.